# How to get HTML content using PhantomJS after X seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, phantomjs, web-crawler

How to get the content of website after 10 seconds using PhantomJS? In my website for example, I have script that do setTimeout then change the DOM. I need to feach the website html with that change.

I can't find any working answers.

Comment: This post is old, but perhaps it will help: http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2013/07/02/phantomjs-wait-for-it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
page.open('http://example.com', function(status) {
    console.log('Page load status: ' + status);
    if (status === 'success') {
        setTimeout(function(){
            fs.write('example.html', page.content, 'a');
            console.log('Page saved');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 10000);
    }
});
```